# Codename one: Increase height of dialog

Tags: codenameone

I am unable to display complete text message in dialog.To view the complete text I need to scroll down that is not appealing on dialog box.I want to display complete text message without scrolling or without cropping text. 
please check attached image[image]

I have used codename one designer to build dialog.
I used this method"Dialog.show("Title","Message Body", "OK", null); " to show  dialog.
 I have tried below methods but those weren't worked .
dialog.setHeight()
dialog.setPreferedSize().

Can you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you styled the dialog differently than the default. Make sure all components are styled with the same padding/margin/font for selected, unselected & pressed states otherwise size calculations might be flawed.

Also verify that the dialog is shown from the EDT as weird things can happen otherwise. E.g. if you invoke it from the native thread.

I just verified this works with a default theme on the EDT as such:

```
Form hi = new Form("Dialog", BoxLayout.y());

Button b = new Button("Show Dialog");
hi.add(b);
b.addActionListener(e -> Dialog.show("Account Locked", "Maximum allowed invalid attempts exceeded. Please contact your bank to unlock or Re-register through the internet banking portal", "OK", null));
hi.show();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: still getting same issue.

Comment: I added another potential pitfall and working test case. If you have a banking application you should probably have an enterprise account in which case we can help you more closely through support